# Django Testing Framework with login decorators - do they work? Error with reverse

Tags: django, testing

I am using the Django testing framework (which is useful, but feels clunky and awkward). A test keeps failing, and the traceback leads me to believe it's an issue with the login decorators. Here are the tests, the error, and the relevant code:

```
class TestMain(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['timetracker']

    def test_login(self):
        c = Client()
        login = c.login(username='testclient', password='not.a.real.password')
        self.failUnless(login, 'Could not log in')

    def test_main(self):
        c = Client()
        login = c.login(username='testclient', password='not.a.real.password')
        self.failUnless(login, 'Could not log in')

        response = c.get('/', follow=True)
        print response.content
        #assert response.status_code == 200, response.status_code




markov:biorhythm vinceb$ nosetests -v --with-django
test_login (biorhythm.timetracker.tests.test_urls.TestMain) ... ok
test_main (biorhythm.timetracker.tests.test_urls.TestMain) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_main (biorhythm.timetracker.tests.test_urls.TestMain)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinceb/Code/python/biorhythm/timetracker/tests/test_urls.py", line 20, 

in test_main
        response = c.get('/', follow=True)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 281, in get
 [...]
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 792, in render_node
        return node.render(context)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 382, in render
        raise e
    NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '<django.contrib.auth.decorators._CheckLogin object at 0x22d4650>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'report_type': u'this_week'}' not found.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 1.112s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database...
markov:biorhythm vinceb$ 






@login_required
def time(request):
    # initials
    from biorhythm.timetracker.forms import TimeForm, TimeFormSet
    from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

    # instantiate our formset factory
    TimeSet = formset_factory(TimeForm, extra=1)
    formset = None

    # sorting worklogs
    order_by = ordered(request)
    success = None
```

What's really strange is that keyword args being inserted into the request, leading me to think it's a template request.

EDIT: more code

```
urlpatterns = patterns('biorhythm.timetracker.views',

    # Home
    url(r'^/?$', 'time', name='home'),

    # CSV exports
    url(r'^reports/csv/(?P<from_date>\d{8})/(?P<to_date>\d{8})/?$', 'export_csv_report', name='csv_out'),   
    url(r'^dashboard/csv/?$', 'export_qbcsv', name='csv_report'),

    # Reports
    url(r'^summary/?$', 'reports', name='reports'),
    (r'^summary/(?P<from_date>\d{8})/(?P<to_date>\d{8})/?$', 'reports'),
    (r'^summary/(?P<report_type>.*?)/?$', 'reports'),

    # test
    (r'new_dashboard/$', 'new_dashboard'),
    url(r'remove_query/(?P<position>.*?)/$', 'remove_query', name='remove_query'),


    # Aggregate timesheets
    url(r'^dashboard/$', 'new_dashboard', name='dashboard'),
    url(r'old_dashboard/$', 'dashboard', name='old_dashboard'),
    (r'^dashboard/(?P<user_id>.*?)/?$', 'dashboard'),
    (r'^dashboard/(?P<from_date>\d{8})/(?P<to_date>\d{8})/?$', 'dashboard'),
)



@login_required
def time(request):
    # initials
    from biorhythm.timetracker.forms import TimeForm, TimeFormSet
    from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

    # instantiate our formset factory
    TimeSet = formset_factory(TimeForm, extra=1)
    formset = None

    # sorting worklogs
    order_by = ordered(request)
    success = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, ADDITION
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
        # we have to make sure we have a matching contenttype for this model
        # normally we will, but first entry may not have this
        worklog, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(name='worklog', app_label='timetracker', model='worklog')

        # pertinent fields
        dats = 'project duration note category start_date'.split()

        # instantiate formset
        formset = TimeSet(request.POST)
        for i, form in enumerate(formset.forms):
            labs = ['form-%d-%s' % (i, d) for d in dats]
            project, duration, note, category, start_date = [request.POST.get(l, None) for l in labs]
            check_against = [project, duration, note, start_date] 

            # Checks that required fields have been filled with input longer than 0.
            if 0 not in [len(x) for x in check_against]:
                if form.is_valid():
                    project, duration, note, category, start_date = [form.cleaned_data.get(l, None) for l in dats]

                    if None not in check_against:
                        # this is a form we can process & save so let's
                        # get our pk for logging activity
                        instance = form.save(commit=False)
                        if instance:
                            # default values and save again
                            instance.start_date = form.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
                            instance.user = request.user
                            instance.save()

                            # Output a nice message to the client
                            s = 's' if duration > 1 else '' # pluralization!
                            message = "%s hour%s spent %s on %s" % (duration, s, note, project.name)
                            request.user.message_set.create(message=message)

                            # Append this action (addition) to the LogEntry table
                            _send_LogEntry(request.user.pk, worklog.id, worklog.id,
                                           force_unicode(project), message)


                            success = True
                else:
                    # Form _not_ valid. Continue outputting the formset with error messages.
                    pass
            else:
                # Form missing required field
                continue  
        if success is True:
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

    # get our data
    worklogs = Worklog.objects.select_related().filter(user=request.user.id).order_by(order_by, '-id')
    time_week = worklogs.filter(start_date__gte=start_of_week()).aggregate(Sum('duration'))
    time_day = worklogs.filter(start_date__gte=today()).aggregate(Sum('duration'))
    #time_week = worklogs.filter(start_date__gte=start_of_week()).objects.objects.get_total_time()
    #time_day = worklogs.filter(start_date__gte=today()).objects.get_total_time()

    reports = return_time_report()

    # instantiate projects for initial data for form for the last 14 days
    # was 30 days, now 14 at Nik's request -J
    month = datetime.timedelta(days=14)
    worklog_projects = worklogs.filter(start_date__gte=today()-month)
    projects = dict.fromkeys([p.project for p in worklog_projects]).keys()

    if not formset:
        initial_data = [{'project':p.id, 'start_date':'today'} for p in projects]
        formset = TimeSet(initial=initial_data)
    has_logs = True if int(worklogs.count()) > 0 else False
    logs = paginate(request, worklogs, 'worklogs')
    logs_list = logs.object_list


    # Initialize categories from a query object, so they can be sent to JQuery
    # via JSON to make auto-complete work.
    cat_list = []
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        cat_list.append(dict(id=str(c.id), name=c.name))
    cats = json.dumps(cat_list)


    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('log.html', {'formset':formset, 'worklogs':logs_list, 'v':locals(), 't':reports}, context)
```

That's the entire view.

This is a huge post, so the template is here: http://dpaste.com/110860/

Comment: This clearly isn't all the relevant code. Your view function is unfinished (it doesn't return an HttpResponse of any sort), and you left out the URLconfs, which are critical to debugging any NoReverseMatch error. There is currently no way for us to find the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error log reported there tells you most of what you need to know:

First you've got:

```
in test_main
        response = c.get('/', follow=True)
```

Which means it's dying while trying to process that request. Next:

```
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 281, in get
 [...]
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 792, in render_node
        return node.render(context)
```

It's dying while rendering a node in the template, which means it's **getting** to the template, not dying at the login. Last:

```
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 382, in render
        raise e
    NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '<django.contrib.auth.decorators._CheckLogin object at 0x22d4650>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'report_type': u'this_week'}' not found.
```

It's raising an exception while trying to reverse a url in your template, which means you called the `{% url %}` tag somewhere with the path to your view function and the argument "this_week", but that's not the appropriate way to call your view function according to your URLconf.

Fix your `{% url %}` tag or your view function definition and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for the good response. I've had NoReverseMatch issues before, but this is difficult because everything renders perfectly in a browser. What could cause this to occur on in a test?

Comment: Post the template code, your URLconf and the rest of your view function and maybe we can figure it out...

Comment: Ok, posted, let me know if you need more.

Comment: I took a look at what you posted, and also found the trac repository for what looks like an earlier version of your project at: https://trac.genomecenter.ucdavis.edu/projects/biorhythm/browser/trunk/ Your template calls custom tags, includes other templates, and calls custom methods on your objects... figuring out where that reverse is being called is nearly impossible for someone who doesn't know the code... But find where that {'report_type': u'this_week'} is coming from and you'll find the real culprit, as well as the answer to why it's different in the test client.

Comment: It's a collaborative project with a lot of custom stuff, making debugging really difficult. I'll trace it via that string, thanks.

Comment: No problem. I *can* tell you, though, that the login decorators do generally work in the test framework. I've used them extensively and never had them fail with the test client.

Comment: Then it's *so* bizarre that it works through a browser, but not through the test.

Comment: I found the issue: a template was using {% url appname.views.view report_type="this_week" %} and **not** {% url projectname.appname.views.view report_type="this_week" %}

Comment: Gotcha. That'd do it. So glad you were able to find it! You might look at url namespaces (new in Django 1.1). It's a little shorter/cleaner/more explicit for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your regex's in `urls.py`? Maybe the are bogus.

Also check this Bug Ticket [Reverse for '<django.contrib.auth.decorators._CheckLogin object at 0x8ee144c>' not found](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8611)

Btw. this is what the django source-code says around line 382 in defaulttags.py

```
# Try to look up the URL twice: once given the view name, and again
# relative to what we guess is the "main" app. If they both fail,
# re-raise the NoReverseMatch unless we're using the
# {% url ... as var %} construct in which cause return nothing.
```

Comment: The problem is in the arguments he's passing to {% url %}, not in the django codebase. Your first statement is correct, the bug ticket is only a bug insofar as it points to the check_login decorator as the course of the error instead of the view function it's wrapping.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have LOGIN_URL defined in your settings.py file?